# Nessus API client to extract Start and End times of a scan - Ruby script

Tags: ruby, security, scripting, nessus

I have a ruby script I downloaded that connects to the API and can download all the reports in one shot. However, it is critical for me to have the start and end times in the actual filename when I download these reports. I was able to modify my script to remove the 6 garbage characters it automatically appends to the filename and for testing I am able to add in "2x" before the csv extension (i plan to only download csv format).

The issue is that the Nessus API does not provide a variable to be able to extract this start and end time. My only other option is to grab it from the site itself. The actual reports are located at `https://nessus-scanner-ip/#/scans/<id>/hosts`. The Start and End times are listed when visiting that link as content. How can I extract this time and append this to the report filename in military time?

Thanks for any help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#################################################################################################
# Name: Nessus 6 Report Downloader
# Author: Travis Lee
#
# Version: 1.0
# Last Updated: 2/28/2016
#
# Description:  Interactive script that connects to a specified Nessus 6 server using the
#               Nessus REST API to automate mass report downloads. It has the ability to download
#               multiple or all reports/file types/chapters and save them to a folder of
#               your choosing. This has been tested with Nessus 6.5.5 and *should* work with
#               Nessus 6+, YMMV.
#
#               File types include: NESSUS, HTML, PDF, CSV, and DB.
#
#               Chapter types include: Vulnerabilities By Plugin, Vulnerabilities By Host,
#               Hosts Summary (Executive), Suggested Remediations, Compliance Check (Executive),
#               and Compliance Check.
#
# Usage: ruby ./nessus6-report-downloader.rb
#
# Reference: https://<nessus-server>:8834/api
#
#################################################################################################

require 'net/http'
require 'fileutils'
require 'io/console'
require 'date'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

# This method will download the specified file type from specified reports
def report_download(http, headers, reports, reports_to_dl, filetypes_to_dl, chapters_to_dl, rpath, db_export_pw)
        begin
                puts "\nDownloading report(s). Please wait..."

                # if all reports are selected
                if reports_to_dl[0].eql?("all")
                        reports_to_dl.clear
                        # re-init array with all the scan ids
                        reports["scans"].each do |scan|
                                reports_to_dl.push(scan["id"].to_s)
                        end
                end

                # iterate through all the indexes and download the reports
                reports_to_dl.each do |rep|
                        rep = rep.strip
                        filetypes_to_dl.each do |ft|

                                # export report
                                puts "\n[+] Exporting scan report, scan id: " + rep + ", type: " + ft
                                path = "/scans/" + rep + "/export"
                                data = {'format' => ft, 'chapters' => chapters_to_dl, 'password' => db_export_pw}
                                resp = http.post(path, data.to_json, headers)
                                fileid = JSON.parse(resp.body)

                                # check export status
                                status_path = "/scans/" + rep + "/export/" + fileid["file"].to_s + "/status"
                                loop do
                                        sleep(5)
                                        puts "[+] Checking export status..."
                                        status_resp = http.get(status_path, headers)
                                        status_result = JSON.parse(status_resp.body)
                                        break if status_result["status"] == "ready"
                                        puts "[-] Export not ready yet, checking again in 5 secs."
                                end

                                # download report
                                puts "[+] Report ready for download..."
                                dl_path = "/scans/" + rep + "/export/" + fileid["file"].to_s + "/download"
                                dl_resp = http.get(dl_path, headers)

                                # create final path/filename and write to file
                                fname_temp = dl_resp.response["Content-Disposition"].split('"')
                                fname = "#{rpath}/#{fname_temp[1]}"

                                # save ext, then remove last 10 chars (6 garbage plus ext; we'll add ext next
                                ext = File.extname(fname)
                                ff = fname[0..-11]
                                f = ff + ext

                                # append start and end time to filename
                                f2x = f.gsub(ext, "2x"+ext)

                                # write file
                                open(f2x, 'w') { |f|
                                        f.puts dl_resp.body
                                }

                                puts "[+] Downloading report to: #{fname}"
                                #puts reports.scan["starttime"]
                                #reports["scans"].each do |scan|
                                #       printf("%s\n", scan["starttime"])
                                #end
                        end
                end

        rescue StandardError => download_report_error
                puts "\n\nError downloading report: #{download_report_error}\n\n"
                exit
        end
end

# This method will return a list of all the reports on the server
def get_report_list(http, headers)
        begin
                # Try and do stuff
                path = "/scans"
                resp = http.get(path, headers)

                #puts "Number of reports found: #{reports.count}\n\n"

                results = JSON.parse(resp.body)

                printf("%-7s %-50s %-30s %-15s %-15s %-3s\n", "Scan ID", "Name", "Last Modified", "Status", "Start", "End")
                printf("%-7s %-50s %-30s %-15s %-15s %-3s\n", "-------", "----", "-------------", "------", "-----", "---")

                # print out all the reports
                results["scans"].each do |scan|
                #d = DateTime.parse(scan["starttime"])
                #year, month, day, t, hour, min, sec = scan["starttime"].unpack("A4A2A2c1A2A2A2")
                        printf("%-7s %-50s %-30s %-15s %-15s %-3s\n", scan["id"], scan["name"], DateTime.strptime(scan["last_modification_date"].to_s,'%s').strftime('%b %e, %Y %H:%M %Z'), scan["status"], scan["starttime"], scan["not-being-used"])
                #       printf("%-7s %-50s %-30s %-15s %-5s %-3s\n", scan["id"], scan["name"], DateTime.strptime(scan["last_modification_date"].to_s,'%s').strftime('%b %e, %Y %H:%M %Z'), scan["status"], DateTime.parse(scan["starttime"].to_s,'%s').strftime('%2H:%2M:%2s'), scan["starttime"])
                end
                return results

        rescue StandardError => get_scanlist_error
                puts "\n\nError getting scan list: #{get_scanlist_error}\n\n"
                exit
        end
end


# This method will make the initial login request and set the token value to use for subsequent requests
def get_token(http, username, password)
        begin
                path = "/session"
                data = {'username' => username, 'password' => password}
                resp = http.post(path, data.to_json, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')

                token = JSON.parse(resp.body)
                headers = {
                        "User-Agent" => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0',
                        "X-Cookie" => 'token=' + token["token"],
                        "Accept" => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                        "Accept-Language" => 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                        "Accept-Encoding" => 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
                        "Cache-Control" => 'max-age=0',
                        "Content-Type" => 'application/json'
                 }
                return headers

        rescue StandardError => get_token_error
                puts "\n\nError logging in/getting token: #{get_token_error}\n\n"
                exit
        end
end

### MAIN ###

puts "\nNessus 6 Report Downloader 1.0"

# Collect server info
print "\nEnter the Nessus Server IP: "
nserver = gets.chomp.to_s
print "Enter the Nessus Server Port [8834]: "
nserverport = gets.chomp.to_s
if nserverport.eql?("")
        nserverport = "8834"
end

# https object
http = Net::HTTP.new(nserver, nserverport)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

# Collect user/pass info
print "Enter your Nessus Username: "
username = gets.chomp.to_s
print "Enter your Nessus Password (will not echo): "
password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp.to_s

# login and get token cookie
headers = get_token(http, username, password)

# get list of reports
puts "\n\nGetting report list..."
reports = get_report_list(http, headers)
print "Enter the report(s) your want to download (comma separate list) or 'all': "
reports_to_dl = (gets.chomp.to_s).split(",")

if reports_to_dl.count == 0
        puts "\nError! You need to choose at least one report!\n\n"
        exit
end

# select file types to download
puts "\nChoose File Type(s) to Download: "
puts "[0] Nessus (No chapter selection)"
puts "[1] HTML"
puts "[2] PDF"
puts "[3] CSV (No chapter selection)"
puts "[4] DB (No chapter selection)"
print "Enter the file type(s) you want to download (comma separate list) or 'all': "
filetypes_to_dl = (gets.chomp.to_s).split(",")

if filetypes_to_dl.count == 0
        puts "\nError! You need to choose at least one file type!\n\n"
        exit
end

# see which file types to download
formats = []
cSelect = false
dbSelect = false
filetypes_to_dl.each do |ft|
        case ft.strip
        when "all"
          formats.push("nessus")
          formats.push("html")
          formats.push("pdf")
          formats.push("csv")
          formats.push("db")
          cSelect = true
          dbSelect = true
        when "0"
          formats.push("nessus")
        when "1"
          formats.push("html")
          cSelect = true
        when "2"
          formats.push("pdf")
          cSelect = true
        when "3"
          formats.push("csv")
        when "4"
          formats.push("db")
          dbSelect = true
        end
end

# enter password used to encrypt db exports (required)
db_export_pw = ""
if dbSelect
        print "\nEnter a Password to encrypt the DB export (will not echo): "
        db_export_pw = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp.to_s
        print "\n"
end

# select chapters to include, only show if html or pdf is in file type selection
chapters = ""
if cSelect
        puts "\nChoose Chapter(s) to Include: "
        puts "[0] Vulnerabilities By Plugin"
        puts "[1] Vulnerabilities By Host"
        puts "[2] Hosts Summary (Executive)"
        puts "[3] Suggested Remediations"
        puts "[4] Compliance Check (Executive)"
        puts "[5] Compliance Check"
        print "Enter the chapter(s) you want to include (comma separate list) or 'all': "
        chapters_to_dl = (gets.chomp.to_s).split(",")

        if chapters_to_dl.count == 0
                puts "\nError! You need to choose at least one chapter!\n\n"
                exit
        end

        # see which chapters to download
        chapters_to_dl.each do |chap|
                case chap.strip
                when "all"
                  chapters << "vuln_hosts_summary;vuln_by_plugin;vuln_by_host;remediations;compliance_exec;compliance;"
                when "0"
                  chapters << "vuln_by_plugin;"
                when "1"
                  chapters << "vuln_by_host;"
                when "2"
                  chapters << "vuln_hosts_summary;"
                when "3"
                  chapters << "remediations;"
                when "4"
                  chapters << "compliance_exec;"
                when "5"
                  chapters << "compliance;"
                end
        end
end

# create report folder
print "\nPath to save reports to (without trailing slash): "
rpath = gets.chomp.to_s
unless File.directory?(rpath)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(rpath)
end

# run report download
if formats.count > 0
        report_download(http, headers, reports, reports_to_dl, formats, chapters, rpath, db_export_pw)
end

puts "\nReport Download Completed!\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The **"details"** method of the Nessus API  (*https://Nessus_scanner:8834/api#/resources/scans/details*) will return the  start and end Epoch timestamps for a given scan:

- "scan_start": {string}
- "scan_end": {string}

You can then use:

`Time.at(xxxxxxxxxx).strftime("%H%M")`

where "*xxxxxxxxxx*" is the 10 digits Epoch timestamp, to get the military format (HHMM).